# Volume of a tent with canvas stretched from a circular base to a vertical semicircular rod

Tags: calculus, volume

From George Simmons' Calculus With Analytical Geometry, page 229 question 7:

> A tent consists of canvas stretched from a circular base of radius $a$
>   to a vertical semicircular rod fastened to the base at the ends of a
>   diameter.  Find the volume of this tent.
>
> Answer (from pg. 864): $\frac{4}{3}a^3$

At first I thought the question meant that the tent was half a sphere, but the answer and looking at the question further show that's not the case.  I am having a difficult time just visualizing this.  How can the rod be both vertical and attached to the base at two points?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Edit: I think I understand the shape now.  Along the diameter where the rod touch the base the shape the shape of the cross-section perpendicular to the base will be semi-circular.  Along the perpendicular diameter of the tent, the cross-section perpendicular to the base will be linear.  The cross sections in between are some intermediate shape.  That said, I've still not completely convinced myself nor am I sure of the calculation even if this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

Considering just one half of the tent, the canvas can be sectioned into various triangular wedges of thickness $dx$ as you move from one end of the rod to the other.  Both the base and height of each wedge are $\sqrt{a^2 - y^2}$.  Thus our triangle has area $\frac{1}{2}(a^2-y^2)$ and thickness $dx$.  Taking the integral from $0$ to $a$ and multiplying by $4$ as this integral only includes one quadrant of the circle leads us to our answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I once couldn't figure out what this "tent" looks like either. Beside the question, I'm really curious about is half of the tent really stretched like a widge, rather than some "weird" shape, like the long side of the cross section is not a straight segment. because the widge one in figure 7.11 from textbook is really different from the tent one in this question, widge's "semicircle rod" is inclined at an angle of 45°, while the tent's semicircle rod is  perpendicular.

Comment: I found the picture here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3981883/1018230, have no doubt now.